# How to disable Web directory indexing in IIS using web.config file?

Tags: iis-7

How to enable/disable web directory indexing in IIS 7? I am not able to find web.config file. But I can find applicationHand.config file where I saw this line: `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />`

I created web.config file in the same folder and added the following. It's not working.

```
<configuration>
<location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

One more question I have is, is by default web directory indexing is disabled in IIS and Apache2 ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/the-configuration-system-in-iis-7

Comment: Thanks a lot @LexLi